# Implement function in async

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, routes, controller

I want to implement a function in async. This code is for authentication, that if user is logged in, than can't reach the page without login. My code in **app.js** file worked, there is the `isLoggedOut` function, where i can implement, so this code is working, but I want to copy this code to my **controller.js**.

The working code in **app.js**:

```js
 app.get('/explore-random', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
     const count =  Recipe.find().countDocuments();
     const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
     const recipe =  Recipe.findOne().skip(random).exec();
     res.render('explore-random', { title: 'Cooking Blog - Explore Random', recipe } );
 })
```

The **controller.js**, where i want to implement `isLoggedOut` function to `exploreRandom`

```js
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
   if (req.isAuthenticated()) return next();
   res.redirect('/login');
 }
 
 function isLoggedOut(req, res, next) {
   if (!req.isAuthenticated()) return next();
   res.redirect('/home');
 }
 
 /**
 * GET /explore-random
 * Explore Random
 */
 exports.exploreRandom = async (req, res) => {
  try {
      let count = await Recipe.find().countDocuments();
      let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
      let recipe = await Recipe.findOne().skip(random).exec();
      res.render('explore-random', { title: 'Cooking Blog - Explore Random', recipe } );
   } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send({message: error.message || "Error Occured"});
  }
}
```

Comment: The implementation looks fine, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass the exported `exploreRandom` function as a handler to your `app.get` route:

```
const exploreRandom = require('./path/to/explore-random-module');

app.get('/explore-random', isLoggedIn, exploreRandom);
```